# How to do collision detection between two point clouds or a point cloud and a robot end effector model using flexible collision library?

Tags: c++, collision-detection, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I am building a bin-picking demo, and I need to do a collision check between the point cloud which is generated by the laser scanner and the end-effector of the robot.

I'm planning to do this job with fcl(flexible collision library) and pcl(point cloud library). but the examples or tutorial of fcl is very limited. I read the demo in the fcl source code in their github page, and wrote a code sample, but I cannot get it right. the following is the code I wrote:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pcl/point_cloud.h>
#include <pcl/point_types.h>
#include <pcl/io/ply_io.h>
#include <fcl/geometry/bvh/BVH_model.h>
#include <fcl/narrowphase/collision.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr obj1_cloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>());
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr obj2_cloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>());

    pcl::PLYReader ply_reader;
    ply_reader.read(argv[1], *obj1_cloud);
    ply_reader.read(argv[2], *obj2_cloud);

    std::shared_ptr<fcl::BVHModel<fcl::AABB<double>>> model1(new fcl::BVHModel<fcl::AABB<double>>);
    std::shared_ptr<fcl::BVHModel<fcl::AABB<double>>> model2(new fcl::BVHModel<fcl::AABB<double>>);

    model1->beginModel();
    for (int i = 0; i < obj1_cloud->points.size(); i++)
    {
        fcl::Vector3d point;
        point(0) = obj1_cloud->points[i].x;
        point(1) = obj1_cloud->points[i].y;
        point(2) = obj1_cloud->points[i].z;
        model1->addVertex(point);
    }
    model1->endModel();
    model1->computeLocalAABB();

    model2->beginModel();
    for (int i = 0; i < obj2_cloud->points.size(); i++)
    {
        fcl::Vector3d point;
        point(0) = obj2_cloud->points[i].x;
        point(1) = obj2_cloud->points[i].y;
        point(2) = obj2_cloud->points[i].z;
        model2->addVertex(point);
    }
    model2->endModel();
    model2->computeLocalAABB();

    fcl::Transform3<double> pose1 = fcl::Transform3<double>::Identity();
    fcl::Transform3<double> pose2 = fcl::Transform3<double>::Identity();

    fcl::CollisionRequest<double> collision_request;
    collision_request.gjk_solver_type = fcl::GJKSolverType::GST_INDEP;

    fcl::CollisionResult<double> collision_result;

    fcl::detail::MeshCollisionTraversalNode<fcl::AABB<double>> traveral_node;

    if (!fcl::detail::initialize(traveral_node, *model1, pose1, *model2, pose2, collision_request, collision_result))
        std::cout << "initialize error" << std::endl;
    fcl::detail::collide(&traveral_node);
}
```

This code can pass the compile but always gives me the error, when it is running.

"initialize error
Segmentation fault"

Can anyone help me to get it right? Thank you for your helping!

Comment: Up to which point does it get before segfaulting? What did you find when you stepped through the program with a debugger?

Comment: @MaxLanghof When I run the debugger, it throws me a message "_Exception thrown at 0x00007FF69C6F87EE in fcl_test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000000000D8._" There is a problem in the initialization `fcl::detail::initialize(traveral_node, *model1, pose1, *model2, pose2, collision_request, collision_result) ` , but I don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK from the source code of `fcl`, `MeshCollisionTraversalNode` is supposed to be used  for `BVHModel` whose `ModelType` is `BVH_MODEL_TRIANGLES`. In your program, you only add all the vertices from point cloud to the `BVHModel`, so its `ModelType` is `BVH_MODEL_POINTCLOUD`, which is not meeting the requirement of `MeshCollisionTraversalNode`.

I think you have two ways to solve the problem:

One is to run triangulation on the point cloud (Refer to: http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/greedy_projection.php) and construct a `BVHModel` of `BVH_MODEL_TRIANGLES`. You might also need to use convex decomposition before collision detection if the mesh model generated from `pcl` is concave.

The other way is to use octree as the representation of the point cloud. You can refer to [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58163625/1755026) for further details.

Comment: Thank you! Solved my problem with octree way.